# How to test whether people remembered more items given an intervention administered within subjects?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, repeated-measures, stata, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have 20 individuals who memorised 5 lists of information. They immediately recalled the information, then at the end of the day either received an interventional 'cue' or nothing prior to recalling the information again. This was performed on two separate days with a different set of lists (i.e., this was a randomised crossover study).

I want to see if there is a statistically significant difference in the information recalled using the intervention or not. Would a sign ranked test be appropriate just grouping the information and testing intervention vs non intervention for changes in information recalled? Or would an ANOVA be more appropriate?

I have Stata if that helps.
example of headings used for workings

Participant Number,    intervention,    time,      case,     correct,      percentage correct,

example info

```
Number intventn time case correct  percentage correct
        1   2   1   6   21      26.92307692
        1   2   1   7   14      25.45454545
        1   2   1   8   16      21.62162162
        1   2   1   9   18      35.29411765
        1   2   1   10  15      19.23076923
        1   1   1   1   13      16.04938272
        1   1   1   2   6       10.71428571
        1   1   1   3   4       5.194805195
        1   1   1   4   7       14.28571429
        1   1   1   5   6        8
        3   2   1   6   37      47.43589744
        3   2   1   7   28      50.90909091
        3   2   1   8   31      41.89189189
        3   2   1   9   24      47.05882353
        3   2   1   10  32      41.02564103
```

Comment: What is the response exactly? Is it number of items recalled out of some total number of items? Can you clarify the nature of the lists?

Comment: its the number of items recalled. the lists are items of information, for example it i describe pain, i describe its site, position severity, etc, therefore site, position and severity would each receive a mark.

Comment: Num interventn time    case correct  percentage correct
1 2 1 6 21 26.92307692
1 2 1 7 14 25.45454545
1 2 1 8 16 21.62162162
1 2 1 9 18 35.29411765
1 2 1 10 15 19.23076923
1 1 1 1 13 16.04938272
1 1 1 2 6 10.71428571
1 1 1 3 4 5.194805195
1 1 1 4 7 14.28571429
1 1 1 5 6 8

Comment: sorry went wrong above

Comment: I've posted an example of the data on next post. Its a crossover so the cases he recalled were 1-5 and 6-10 on different days intervention or no intervention. The amount of info in each case was different but total number of items the same over 5 cases. For the written version Shap wilk <0.05 for correct & percent corr for intervention group so I did Kwallis (can i do that as its grouping all the results of cases together?). my stata command was 'kwallis percentage correct, by(intervention)'

Comment: no intervention time   case correct percentage correct
1 2 1 6 21 26.92307692
1 2 1 7 14 25.45454545
1 2 1 8 16 21.62162162
1 2 1 9 18 35.29411765
1 2 1 10 15 19.23076923
1 1 1 1 13 16.04938272
1 1 1 2 6 10.71428571
1 1 1 3 4 5.194805195
1 1 1 4 7 14.28571429
1 1 1 5 6 8
3 2 1 6 37 47.43589744
3 2 1 7 28 50.90909091
3 2 1 8 31 41.89189189
3 2 1 9 24 47.05882353
3 2 1 10 32 41.02564 i then looked at a verbal recall of the information the same way shap wilk was>0.05 so should i do anova for this other data? Or have i done it wrong ?

Comment: So each person is recalling each list of items 2x. Do both sets have 5 lists? Is the set that goes w/ intervention j counterbalanced across interventions? Are the interventions counterbalanced by order? Are there the same number of items on every list? How many? Are the items w/i a list thematically related (eg to pain, as in your response above), but distinct from other lists?

Comment: Yes they recall the list immediately after memorisation and  8hrs later. The list set is counterbalanced across intervention. No the lists have different information points. - essentially each list is distinst containing the same characteristic but dif diagnosis- history of illness(always descrive same way site, duration , past history, allergies etcalways following same format. Number of items from 50-70 points,total of points is almost the same (over the 5 lists recalled). I tried to keep them similar set 1=81,56,77,49,75, set 2=78,55,74,51,78 that was the reason i counterbalanced them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a randomized crossover design, you should be looking at intervention, sequence, and potentially list as independent variables.  My hunch is that your data will be pretty normally distributed (if your dependent variable is number of items recalled) and ANOVA will be fine, but you can check that assumption and use non-parametric approach if warranted.

Comment: If the DV is number of items recalled out of a total number of items, it will be distributed as a binomial, not normally.